# PathAnimation diagram link token animation error

Tags: javascript, angular, gojs

I have configured **pathAnimation** diagram from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAnnW.png) and while at the time of loading it gives below screen shot error and does not loading token animation.

[image]

My sample code repo [ink](https://dev.azure.com/sharepointempower/Airfresh_AnandBhai/_git/GoJS-Path-Animation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvicrj31JOM) link by usage of **this** keyword in code and it works as expected.